# Is there an alternative to type checking in this C# code?

Tags: c#

I'm currently working on a tree structure of nodes where each node should be able to tell if it is equivalent to another one. Each node class is a subclass of QueryNode.
To check for equivalency, nodes compare if they are of the same subclass and have equal member values (of course there's more things involved, but this is the part that bugs me):

```
class VersionNode : QueryNode
{
    VersionModifier m_versionModifier;

    internal VersionModifier VersionModifier
    { get { return this.m_versionModifier; } }

    // ...

    protected override bool AreMembersEquivalent(QueryNode other)
    {
        VersionNode otherNodeAsVersionNode = other as VersionNode;

        if (otherNodeAsVersionNode == null)
            return false;
        else
            return (this.m_versionModifier == otherNodeAsVersionNode.VersionModifier);
    }
}
```

I feel this may not be an optimal solution because it involves casting. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: The code will look more 'elegant' if you make your tab size 2 spaces, and shorten your local variable names.

Comment: BTW you have direct access to m_versionModifier of the other instance. No need to go via a property  :)  The 'this' is also unneeded.

Comment: I prefer verbose code to stylish looking one since reading Paul Graham's Ansi Common Lisp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no.  Casting (and even unboxing to a degree) is not expensive.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
protected override bool AreMembersEquivalent(QueryNode other)
    {
        if (!(other is VersionNode))
           return false;
        ...
}
```

Comment: It doesn't help here, since you need to manipulate "other" as a VersionNode to access its property. Safe cast with "as" is the good way to go.

Comment: Agreed you'll have to cast it anyway if you continue. Just throwing it out as an alternative. Funny thing is the 'is' and 'as' operator are actually both implemented as the isinst IL opcode, so there's really no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the odd cast isn't going to hurt you much. What are you doing, physics modelling?

Comment: Writing tests for some minor optimizations on database queries. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yeah, this kind of thing is a red herring then. Your real gains lie elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It's not more elegant, but it's possibly more explicit:

```
protected override bool AreMembersEquivalent(QueryNode other)
{
   if (GetType() == other.GetType())
   {
       return (VersionModifier == other.VersionModifier);
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean?  This code will tell you if two objects that both inherit from QueryNode are of the same type.